# Subset one special day over a period of time

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time-series, subset

I have a dataframe that contains daily data over 50 years. I want to subset the data of every May 1st of each year.

I already converted the date like this:

```
Temp[,1] = as.Date(Temp[,1],format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at `?format()`

Comment: To expand @Sotos comment, try: `Temp[format(Temp[,1],"%m%d")=="0501",]`.